# Custom Properties value in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I'd like to directly control custom properties of my empties and bones in Animation Nodes tree, to avoid location, scale and rotation manipulation. "Object Attribute Input" doesn't work, even after using copy data path.

My workaround is to create empty with scale controlled by custom properties, and this scale attribute is used in Animation Nodes tree, but I hope, I can do it .

Comment: Hello, could you share a screenshot or two of your setup ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expression node to control property of object. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on a property to get code. use that code inside expression node to get or set the data.

For example an object Empty has two custom properties `A` and `B`. We can get value of `A`
using `bpy.data.objects["Empty"]["A"]`. Similarly we can set value to `B` using `bpy.data.objects["Empty"]["B"]=x` where x is the data we provide.

[image]

Or you can replace the object name and property name by,

[image]

Answer (score -2):

the default Animation Nodes do not have 'Bone' sockets, [ClockMender](https://clockmender.uk/blender/animation-nodes/) wrote some nodes that would be useful for that.

Comment: Please help us making this site a real knowledge base and add *how* to use it. *Link-only answers* are discouraged, if the link goes down the answer becomes useless. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer Thanks